# How to inject code before </body> by extension in all Magento pages

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, extensions

I need to build custom extension (code pool 'community') that should add some Javascript just before the HTML body tag is closed.

So far after some research it seems that the most elegant way to do this is to use 'before_body_end' reference. I found [this article](http://www.codexpedia.com/magento/add-a-block-to-the-before_body_end-block-in-magento/) and recreated all steps exactly as described (except I'm using the 'community' code pool) on a fresh clean default Magento CE 1.9.2.1 installation. But nothing happens. The extension is enabled in 'Configuration/Advanced', cache is cleaned, no errors at all... The custom phtml isn't loaded.

Can anyone describe (or refer to) what steps should be done to make it work?

Maybe there is another way (not with 'before_body_end') to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

This requirement can be ***easily achieve by a backend setting.***

Magento have provide *`an input field to system configure`* where you can *`put any html/script code`*  and that will be  `inject code before </body>`.

Just goto ***Admin>System>Configuration>Design>Footer***

Put your `html and script code at` field `Miscellaneous HTML`.

[image]

If want do this by **codexpedia. extension** then there are *some  location modification* required on ***your layout xml and template phtml***

Put addblock.xml from `app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/`  to `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/`

Put  myblock.phtml from  `app/design/frontend/default/default/templat/addblock/`
to `app/design/frontend/base/default/templat/addblock/`

***As i  move this two file to base package,that it should be call frontend thmes***

Comment: Appreciate this, thanks. The 1st solution isn't automated. The 2nd - I already tried to move these files to 'base/default', but without success. Anyway, the steps described in "www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/introducing-magento-layout/" actually work (but this answer can't be answered due to don't-post-only-link-answer rule.

Comment: A couple things...first using the database to store page JavaScript only results in untracked code and a loss of accountability. Second, the 'base' design package is owned by the Magento core and should not be internally modified. From my experience the safest and cleanest way to accomplish this task is to make a JS file containing the desired functionality and using the local.xml file to add it to the appropriate block.  Overriding the page/html/footer.phtml file locally is also totally acceptable.